# VueJS fetch promises

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, fetch

I have a component:

```
Vue.component('mail-list', {
  props: ['userInbox'],
  template:
  `
  <div>
    <p>{{userInbox}}</p>
  </div>
  `
  });
```

I want to print in p tag props content which is the result of **created** function

```
let options = {
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pollingId: null,
  },

  created: function() {

    let users = fetch('/inbox')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(aJson => {return (aJson)})
    this.userInbox = users
  }
}
let vm = new Vue(options);
```

But this is only returning a promise which I can not work with.

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

Promise has this content:

```
{ '1':
   Mail {
     id: 1,
     from: 'pep@mydomain.com',
     to: 'mar@mydomain.com',
     subject: 'Hi Mar',
     body: 'This is a test from pep to mar',
     timestamp: 1590647288599 },
  '6':
   Mail {
     id: 6,
     from: 'nil@mydomain.com',
     to: 'mar@mydomain.com',
     subject: 'By Mar',
     body: 'This is a test from nil to mar',
     timestamp: 1590647288599 } }
```

I have to display in p tag the from and subject attributes of each.

Comment: I gave this question a negative point. The reason is that as its name implies it is a promise and may not have the value. A simple search on promise could explain this very well. Worse is that this post sits top when you search for fetch or promise and wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't forget to register userInbox in your data.
Second, assign it in promise callback

```
let options = {
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pollingId: null,
    userInbox: ''
  },

  created: function() {

    let users = fetch('/inbox')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(aJson => {
      this.userInbox = aJson
    })

  }
}
let vm = new Vue(options);
```